# Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock game

Tags: java, rock-paper-scissors, rags-to-riches

There was a fairly strangely written RPSLS game on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407987/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-not-returning-anything).

That inspired me (read: I was bored and figured it would be fun) to write a better one. But I'm not sure what else there is that could be done to make it prettier.

This is my latest version:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {
    public enum Choices {
        ROCK("rock") {
            @Override
            public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() {
                if (winsAgainst.isEmpty()) {
                    winsAgainst.add(SCISSORS);
                    winsAgainst.add(LIZARD);
                }
                return winsAgainst;
            }
        },
        PAPER("paper") {
            @Override
            public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() {
                if (winsAgainst.isEmpty()) {
                    winsAgainst.add(ROCK);
                    winsAgainst.add(SPOCK);
                }
                return winsAgainst;
            }
        },
        SCISSORS("scissors") {
            @Override
            public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() {
                if (winsAgainst.isEmpty()) {
                    winsAgainst.add(PAPER);
                    winsAgainst.add(LIZARD);
                }
                return winsAgainst;
            }
        },
        LIZARD("lizard") {
            @Override
            public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() {
                if (winsAgainst.isEmpty()) {
                    winsAgainst.add(SPOCK);
                    winsAgainst.add(PAPER);
                }
                return winsAgainst;
            }
        },
        SPOCK("spock") {
            @Override
            public List<Choices> getWinsAgainst() {
                if (winsAgainst.isEmpty()) {
                    winsAgainst.add(ROCK);
                    winsAgainst.add(SCISSORS);
                }
                return winsAgainst;
            }
        };

        private String keyword;

        protected List<Choices> winsAgainst;

        private Choices(String keyword) {
            this.keyword = keyword;
            this.winsAgainst = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public String getKeyword() {
            return keyword;
        }

        public abstract List<Choices> getWinsAgainst();
    }

    public void printUserOptions() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("Input your choice of one of the following:");
        for (Choices choice : Choices.values()) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
            stringBuilder.append(choice.getKeyword());
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }

    public Choices getUserChoice() {
        boolean isUserChoiceValid = false;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        Choices userChoice = null;
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            do {
                String userChoiceString = bufferedReader.readLine();
                isUserChoiceValid = validateUserChoice(userChoiceString);
                if (!isUserChoiceValid) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter one of the valid options.");
                } else {
                    userChoice = Choices.valueOf(userChoiceString.toUpperCase());
                }
            } while (!isUserChoiceValid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("There was an error while reading from input.", e);
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return userChoice;
    }


    public boolean validateUserChoice(String userChoice) {
        for (Choices choice : Choices.values()) {
            if (choice.getKeyword().equals(userChoice)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Choices getComputerChoice() {
        return Choices.values()[new Random().nextInt(Choices.values().length)];
    }

    public void evaluateResult(Choices userChoice, Choices computerChoice) {
        if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
            return;
        }

        if (userChoice.getWinsAgainst().contains(computerChoice)) {
            System.out.println("You won!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The computer won.");
        }
    }

    public void execute() {
        printUserOptions();
        Choices userChoice = getUserChoice();
        Choices computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You picked: " + userChoice.getKeyword());
        System.out.println("Computer picked: " + computerChoice.getKeyword());
        System.out.println("");
        evaluateResult(userChoice, computerChoice);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RockPaperScissors rockPaperScissors = new RockPaperScissors();
        rockPaperScissors.execute();
    }
}
```

Current output:

> ```
> Input your choice of one of the following: rock paper scissors lizard spock
> scissors
>
> You picked: scissors
> Computer picked: spock
>
> The computer won.
> ```

Apart from the boilerplate on the enums which I find that while despite being lengthy, it does make it easier to read the code on the long-run.

Is there anything specific that could be done to improve the app, make it more scalable, maybe make it easy to detach it from being console-only (look at those `System.out`s, those keep it from being easily improved from one framework to another)? What can you think of as an improvement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice implementation. There are a few items I would criticise, but, overall I am impressed.

### Choices

1. Enums should have singlular names. `Choices` should be just `Choice`. This would eliminate problems like `public Choices getUserChoice() {...}` which returns just one thing despite the return value.
2. Your class is not safe. It is public, and has a public method `public abstract List<Choices> getWinsAgainst();` which returns a 'live' list. If I were a mean player, I would do:

   ```
   public static final void main (String[] args) {
       Choices[] opts = Choices.values();
       for (Choices c : opts) {
           c.getWinsAgains().clear();
       }
       Choices myChoice = opts[0];
       for (int i = 1; i < opts.length; i++) {
           myChoice.getWinsAgainst().add(opts[i]);
       }

       // .... now the user only ever chooses myChoice .... ;-) Happy Christmas!!! 
   }
   ```

   You need to encapsulate your data correctly. Private data should be private... what you should consider, instead of the `getWinsAgainst()` method instead have something like `public boolean winsAgainst(Choice otherChoice);` which will return true if the internal data says it should. This does not leak data.
3. While we are looking there, the data is not thread safe. Enums are supposed to be safe to use concurrently... and yours is not. Two threads accessing the enums at the same time may overpopulate, or corrupt, the winning strategies. One option to solve this is to use a static initializer block:

   ```
   public enum Choice {
       ROCK("rock"),
       PAPER("paper"),
       SCISSORS("scissors"),
       LIZARD("lizard"),
       SPOCK("spock");

       static {
           ROCK.winsAgainst.add(SCISSORS);
           ROCK.winsAgainst.add(LIZARD);
           PAPER.winsAgainst.add(ROCK);
           PAPER.winsAgainst.add(SPOCK);
           SCISSORS.winsAgainst.add(PAPER);
           SCISSORS.winsAgainst.add(LIZARD);
           LIZARD.winsAgainst.add(SPOCK);
           LIZARD.winsAgainst.add(PAPER);
           SPOCK.winsAgainst.add(ROCK);
           SPOCK.winsAgainst.add(SCISSORS);
       }

       private final String keyword;

       private final List<Choice> winsAgainst = new ArrayList<>();

       private Choice(String keyword) {
           this.keyword = keyword;
       }

       public String getKeyword() {
           return keyword;
       }

       public boolean winsAgainst(Choice otherChoice) {
           return winsAgainst.contains(otherChoice);
       }
   }
   ```

   That should be almost the same bhaviour (except that it is called `Choice`, it is thread-safe, and that the enum fields are now also final, and private).

   Static initializer blocks are uncommon, but can be very, very useful.

### Remaining code

- Instead of creating a new Buffered reader each time you get user input, you should instead create the buffered reader immediately on `System.in`, and then pass that reader in to the `getUserChoice` method. While your exception handling in there is commendable, you would be better served by doing that outside the method in your `execute` method, and using a [try-with-resources approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). I really like the use of the do-while loop though. Good choice... but, consider doing a `while(true)`, and just returning immediately with a valid choice from inside the loop. No need for managing the cumbersome `isUserChoiceValid` variable.
- Random - you create a new one each time the computer plays:

  > ```
  > return Choices.values()[new Random().nextInt(Choices.values().length)];
  > ```

  There is no value in that (in fact, it's bad). You should simply create a static, or class field, and then reuse it:

  ```
   private static final Random rand = new Random();

   return Choices.values()[rand.nextInt(Choices.values().length)];
  ```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to look through the code! :) I'm actually most amazed by point **#3**. At first, I was trying to use instance initializers to add the right `Choice`s to the lists, but instance initializers were forbidden for the enum - and I didn't think of the `static` initializer blocks - so it's shorter, more efficient, and actually safe! I honestly didn't even think of **#2** though. :| now I will. Thank you again, this will help me be aware of these mistakes! :)

Comment: +1 but... I think EnumSet<Choice> would be an improvement on List<Choice>.  Also, everybody working with enums should be reminded to reread the related chapter in _Effective Java, 2nd Edition_.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason - good point about the EnumSet ... hmmm. Why did I not take it that step further. Drat.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason now that you mention it, I forgot about `EnumSet<T>` in this particular case even though I've used them before, after seeing the following answer on SO by Gexicide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24651741/2413303

Comment: public and private have nothing to do with security. The player of your game is not writing code that you are executing. If they are, they can just not call your function and instead write their own function that always returns that they win, or modify your source code. Suggesting that private is a security feature is dangerous.

Comment: @DavidStone - Not sure how you interpreted my suggestion as a security issue, it's an encapsulation failure, leaking data out of the container that should not be leaked. Security is not something I mentioned anywhere, not sure why you think I was suggesting that. If I had security in mind, well, that would be pointless... reflection being there, and everything.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, it should have either been immutable, or I just should have gone with the static initializer rather than with lazy initialization. I went with lazy because I didn't think of static, and to be honest I didn't really think of it - although it even felt somewhat awkward to write down that`.contains()` for the win check.

Comment: @rolfl: After saying the class is not "safe", you say "If I were a mean player, I would do:" implying that you have to protect against other people writing source code. That is what I was objecting to.

Comment: @DavidStone in a real work environment, sometimes you might. I ran into problems once because I should have made some things `final`, but I forgot. :|

Answer (score 1):

I'd love an initialization like

```
ROCK(PAPER, SCISSORS), ...
```

enlisting all the "wins against". However, this is impossible as when the constructor gets executed, the enum literals don't yet exist. The strings would do, but this is not especially nice. Initial letters would be perfect but SCISSORS and SPOCK collide.

So I chose the second letters, which is probably good to *show what can be done*, but I surely would not recommend really doing it.

```
public enum Choice {
    ROCK("CI"), // C = sCissors, I =lIzzard, ...
    PAPER("OP"),
    SCISSORS("AI"),
    LIZARD("PA"),
    SPOCK("OC"),
    ;

    Choice(String winsAgainstString) {
        this.winsAgainstString = winsAgainstString;
        this.keyword = name().toLowerCase();
    }

    public boolean winsAgainst(Choice choice) {
        final char secondChar = choice.name().charAt(1);
        // there's no `contains` for chars
        return winsAgainstString.indexOf(secondChar) != -1;
    }

    private final String winsAgainstString;
    @Getter private final String keyword;
}
```

No need to specify the `keyword` in the initializer when it can be so trivially computed. The [Lombok Getter annotation](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) does exactly the expected thing.

Comment: `this.keyword = name().toLowerCase();` smart. I'm surprised I didn't think of that. I don't really like the idea of specifying the relation in a string, though. Although it is a fine alternative.

Comment: @Zhuinden The string itself is fine, but using the *second* letter is terrible. For things like King, Queen, Rook, ..., the initial letters are unique and well established and I'd use them.

Comment: if I want to specify them as strings, I may as well, just write out the whole thing and give the constructor a `String...` parameter

Comment: that could actually work pretty well, though.